# How to make a custom action return non-zero

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I'm working with the .NET Installer, and using a custom action executable file.  According to this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if it fails it must return non-zero.  However this is new ground for me and I do not know how to make an executable "return" a value.

How does an custom action executable return a non-zero value and abort the install?

Comment: I know you can use Environment.Exit(0) to exit an application with code 0. Environment.Exit(1). would exit the app with the error code 1. Perhaps you could use something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your executable, simply add an exception handler (try/catch block) and return (Environment.Exit(-1) -1 in the catch block, 0 otherwise.

If it is a third party, then you have less options. Try checking their manual or contact them directly.

Perhaps you can run the executable and see what values it returns from the command line. You may not have to do anything at all other than consuming it in your installer.